# Obter informações dentro de um dicionário

Tags: python

Estou com uma dúvida em relação a um dicionário em um dicionário, eu tenho um código que tem vários usuários em um site,cada um com um nome único e a idade, onde os nomes dos usuários e as idades são usados em chaves em um dicionário. como faço para acessar as informações do `nome`, `sobrenome` e `idade` através de um laço.

```
usuarios = {
    'jsilva': {
        'nome': 'junior',
        'sobrenome': 'silva',
        'idade': 18,
    },
    'rmatheus': {
        'nome': 'roberto',
        'sobrenome': 'matheus',
        'idade': 20,
    },
}
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para exibir as informações dentro de um dicionário eu fiz da seguinte forma

```
for usuario, usuario_info in usuarios.items():
    print("\nUsuário: " + usuario)
    nome_completo = usuario_info['nome'] + " " + usuario_info['sobrenome']
    idade = usuario_info['idade']

    print("Nome completo: " + nome_completo.title())
    print("Idade: " + str(idade))
```

Comment: o .title() serve para deixar as palavras como títulos certo, e como faz para deixar o nome completo em tudo maiúsculo?

Comment: utilizando o método upper()